# Wish the search method for elasticsearch is working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

■The environment

- MacOS
- RailsServer
- Ruby 2.4.1
- Ruby on Rails 5.1.7
- MySQL
- Elasticsearch 7.10.2-SNAPSHOT
- kuromoji

Gems

- elasticsearch (7.4.0)
- elasticsearch-api (7.4.0)
- elasticsearch-model (7.1.0 80822d6)
- elasticsearch-rails (7.1.0 80822d6)
- elasticsearch-transport (7.4.0)

■My wish

Hi I'm japanese.
My wish is that read faster on database to use elasticsearch on rails.
Now i'm trouble with search method on rails.

I will explain the current settings.
First, I think the record on elastic search already input on following below.

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index                  uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   es_project_development Fpu_adXWT9Gtw7KZTh0aDw   1   1       6804            0      3.7mb          3.7mb
```

Second, the setting of index and mapping for elasticsearch are the following below.

```
/models/concerns/project_searchable.rb

module ProjectSearchable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include Elasticsearch::Model

      index_name "es_project_#{Rails.env}"

      settings do
        mappings dynamic: 'false' do
          indexes :id,          type: 'integer'
          indexes :title,   type: 'text', analyzer: 'kuromoji'
          indexes :contents,   type: 'text', analyzer: 'kuromoji'
          indexes :industry,      type: 'text'
...

      def as_indexed_json(*)
        attributes
          .symbolize_keys
          .slice(:id, :title, :contents, :industry, ...)
      end
    end

    class_methods do
      def create_index!
        client = __elasticsearch__.client
        client.indices.delete index: self.index_name rescue nil
        client.indices.create(index: self.index_name,
          body: {
            settings: self.settings.to_hash,
            mappings: self.mappings.to_hash
          })
      end

      def es_search(query)
        __elasticsearch__.search({
          query: {
            multi_match: {
               fields: %w(id title contents industry ...),
               type: 'cross_fields',
              query: query,
               operator: 'and'
            }
          }
        })
      end
    end
  end
```

Third, the view and the controller are the following below.

```
/views/top/index.html.slim

= form_tag search_path, {:method=>"get"}
    table border="0"
        tr
            td
                = text_field_tag 'keyword[name]', nil, class: 'write'
            td
                input.push type="submit" value=""
...
```

```
/controllers/projects_controller.rb

    def search
...
        @keyword = params.dig('keyword', 'name')

        params = ''
        connection = '?'

    ...

            if @keyword.present?
                params = "#{params}#{connection}keyword=#{@keyword}"
                connection = '&'
            end

    ...
```

Last, ProjectSearchable is included in models/project.rb.

```
/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    include ProjectSearchable
...
```

■The problem

On rails console, i typed command

```
Project.es_search('Game')
```

Response was following.
※Game is included in the record

```
#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response:0x007fc1a85621a8
@klass=[PROXY] Project (call 'Project.connection' to establish a connection),
@search=
#<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007fc1a8562248
@definition=
{:index=>"es_project_development",
:type=>nil,
:body=>
{:query=>
{:multi_match=>
{:fields=>
["id",
"title",
"contents",
"industry",
"required",
...
"comment"],
:type=>"cross_fields",
:query=>"Game",
:operator=>"and"}}}},
@klass=[PROXY] Project (call 'Project.connection' to establish a connection),
@options={}>>
```

I think elasticsearch doesn't work.
My opinion of this problem is in search method for elasticsearch.
But i don't have enough knowledge about that.

I really need your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Woah woah woah. Appreciate the effort but I think you have a bit too many details here. That is quite a lot to read and is very difficult to determine exactly what you are having an error with that we can fix. We aren't here to improve functioning code but rather fix broken code. Improving functionality is something for [codereview.se] So please shorten your code so we only have the [mre]. Minimal being the key word here. We don't need to know every little detail unless you think it causes the problem.